# html append to textarea

Tags: html, geolocation, textarea

I have been working on this piece of code to get geolocation on a timer of 10 seconds, result will be displayed in text area. The problem is how do I append new result in without replacing the old ones, and perhaps auto expand textarea if necessary.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>HTML that display geolocation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea rows="50" cols="100" id="demo"></textarea>

    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");
        var timer = setInterval(function () { getLocation() }, 10000);

        function getLocation()
        {
            if (navigator.geolocation)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error)
            }
            else
            {
                x.innerHTML = "Geoloaction is not supported."
            }
        }

        function success(pos)
        {
            var y = pos.coords;
            var z = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
            x.innerHTML = z + "  Latitude: " + y.latitude + " Longitude" + y.longitude;
        }

        function error(err)
        {
            switch (error.code)
            {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, += definitely helped. What happens if I want to add a line break at the end of each entry so they all lined up like a list. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/gmsuLaj9/)

You use `value` for a `textarea` not `innerHTML`. Then you can use `+=` to append text to it.

```
var mTextArea = document.getElementById("demo");
mTextArea.value = "Some text.";
mTextArea.value += " Some other text.";
```

Now if you get the value of the textarea it will be

```
console.log(mTextArea.value);
```

> Some text. Some other text.

**EDIT:**

To make textarea to expand automatically you need to set its `height` to its `scrollHeight`.

```
function resizeTextArea(elm) {
    elm.style.height = elm.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

So if the text is being added to the textarea programmatically then just call the function afterwards like `resizeTextArea(mTextArea);`

If you want it to resize as you type then:

```
var mTextArea = document.getElementById('demo');

mTextArea.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';
});
```

**EDIT 2:**

To start a new line you use `"\n"`.

> "This is the first line.\nThis is the second line."

Comment: Oh my god, how can I forget about the \n....Thank you so much for your inputs, totally solved all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use `+=` instead of `=` to append content to the textarea where you set x.innerHTML:

```
function success(pos){
  var y = pos.coords;
  var z = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  x.innerHTML += z + "  Latitude: " + y.latitude + " Longitude" + y.longitude;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are not using jQuery in there so .append is not an option for you.

For your solution, you can just follow these steps:

1. Get the content of the textarea and put it in a variable.
2. Concatenate what you are trying to append to that variable (txt_area_content+new_to_append)
3. Clear the contents of that textarea and then put what you have concatenated.